# Pandas DataFrame joining 2 tables on <,> conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to remove all sessions after user conversion (and also removing the sessions that happened on the day of conversion)

```
full_sessions = pd.DataFrame(data={'user_id':[1,1,2,3,3], 'visit_no':[1,2,1,1,2], 'date':['20180307','20180308','20180307','20180308','20180308'], 'result':[0,1,1,0,0]})
print full_sessions 

       date  result  user_id  visit_no
0  20180307       0        1         1
1  20180308       1        1         2
2  20180307       1        2         1
3  20180308       0        3         1
4  20180308       0        3         2
```

When did people convert?

```
conversion = full_sessions[full_sessions['result'] == 1][['user_id','date']]
print conversion
   user_id      date
0        1  20180308
2        2  20180307
```

**Ideal output:**

```
       date  result  user_id  visit_no
0  20180307       0        1         1
3  20180308       0        3         1
4  20180308       0        3         2
```

What do I want in SQL?

```
SQL would be:
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM full_sessions
LEFT JOIN conversion
ON 
full_sessions.user_id = conversion.user_id AND full_sessions.date <  conversion.date
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM full_sessions
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM conversion)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC using `merge` in pandas

```
full_sessions.merge(conversion,on='user_id',how='left').loc[lambda x : (x.date_y>x.date_x)|(x.date_y.isnull())].dropna(1)
Out[397]: 
     date_x  result  user_id  visit_no
0  20180307       0        1         1
3  20180308       0        3         1
4  20180308       0        3         2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the dataframes and then filter the rows matching your criteria this way:

```
df_join = full_sessions.join(conversion,lsuffix='',
                            rsuffix='_right',how='left',on='user_id')
print(df_join)

      date  result  user_id  visit_no  user_id_right date_right
0  20180307       0        1         1            1.0   20180308
1  20180308       1        1         2            1.0   20180308
2  20180307       1        2         1            2.0   20180307
3  20180308       0        3         1            NaN        NaN
4  20180308       0        3         2            NaN        NaN
```

And then just keep those with NaN in the right date or with `date_right` smaller than `date`:

```
>>> df_join[df_join.apply(lambda x: x.date < x.date_right 
                          if pd.isna(x.date_right) is False 
                          else True,axis=1)][['date','visit_no','user_id']]

        date  visit_no  user_id
0  20180307         1        1
3  20180308         1        3
4  20180308         2        3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method which maps a series instead of join / merge alternatives.

```
fs['date'] = pd.to_numeric(fs['date'])

s = fs[fs['result'] == 1].set_index('user_id')['date']

result = fs.loc[fs['date'] < fs['user_id'].map(s).fillna(fs['date'].max()+1)]
```

**Result**

```
       date  result  user_id  visit_no
0  20180307       0        1         1
3  20180308       0        3         1
4  20180308       0        3         2
```

**Explanation**

- Create a mapping from `user_id` to conversion date, store it in a series `s`.
- Then just filter on dates prior to conversion dates mapped via `user_id`.
- If no conversion date, then data will be included since we `fillna` with a maximal date.
- Consider using `datetime` objects. I have converted to numeric above for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

using groupby & apply & some final cleanup with reset index, you can express it in 1 *very* long statement:

```
full_sessions.groupby('user_id', as_index=False).apply(
    lambda x: x[:(x.result==1).values.argmax()] if any(x.result==1) else x
).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

outputs:

```
       date  result  user_id  visit_no
0  20180307       0        1         1
3  20180308       0        3         1
4  20180308       0        3         2
```